# Using a trigger property on a different type to the setter property on WPF style

Tags: c#, wpf

I wish to set the opacity of a set of images on my main window to 0.25 when a dependency property on the window itself is false and restore them when the dependency property is true. I have attempted to use a style trigger for this but ran into difficulty when the dependency property was on a different type to the opacity property.

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="IconEnabledStyle" TargetType="Image">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- MenuOptionsEnabled is on main window. Opacity is on Image -->
                <Trigger Property="MenuOptionsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.25"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="MenuOptionsEnabled" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1.0"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

As you can see the Trigger property is on a different type to the Setter property. Is there a way to define the type for both Trigger and Setter property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the problem, you can use `DataTrigger` with `RelativeSource` to find the ancestor `Window`, something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="IconEnabledStyle" TargetType="Image">
    <Style.Triggers>    
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MenuOptionsEnabled, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" 
                    Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.25"></Setter>
       </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Note that the default `Opacity` is already `1`. So you don't need any Trigger to reset it to `1`. When the condition is met, it's set to `0.25`, otherwise it will be automatically reset to the value before.